# Isomorphism of Localizations of polynomials rings

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

Let us consider the polynomial ring $\mathbb{C}[x]$. It is well-known that the maximal ideals are of the form $(x-a)$, for any $a \in \mathbb{C}$. If we consider the corresponding localizations $\mathbb{C}[x]_{(x-a)}$, are these isomorphic?

More in general, it is possible to find a polynomial ring and two maximal ideals inducing non-isomorphic localizations?

Comment: Yes, they are all isomorphic. For your latter claim, try $\mathbb C[X,Y]/(Y^2-X^2-X^3)$. This is a nodal curve. Check any maximal ideal here, and then check the one at $(0,0)$.

Comment: @AndresMejia The OP wants "to find a *polynomial ring* and two maximal ideals...".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The map $$\varphi:\mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]\to\mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]$$ given by $\varphi(X_i)=X_i-a_i$ for all $i=1,\dots,n$ is an automorphism. It extends to an isomorphism
$$\bar\varphi:\mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]_{(X_1,\dots,X_n)}\to\mathbb C[X_1,\dots,X_n]_{(X_1-a_1,\dots,X_n-a_n)}.$$

(The same result holds for polynomial rings over any algebraically closed field.)

Now let us show that $\mathbb R[X]_{(X)}$ is not isomorphic to  $\mathbb R[X]_{(X^2+1)}$. Suppose the contrary and let $\psi:\mathbb R[X]_{(X^2+1)}\to\mathbb R[X]_{(X)}$
be an isomorphism. Since $\psi$ sends the maximal ideal to the maximal ideal we  get an isomorphism between the residue fields, that is, $\mathbb R[X]/(X^2+1)\simeq\mathbb R[X]/(X)$. This is equivalent to $\mathbb C\simeq R$, a contradiction.